# Is there an option to use code writer on unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

The problem I am facing is in Unity.

My code:

```
public class script : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start() {
        Debug.Log("hello,world");
    }

    void Update() {

    }
}
```

And the error is:

> The contents of the ProjectVersion.txt file for the project located in
>   C:/Users/Lalit/New Unity Project are corrupt. Please fix the contents
>   of the file.

Comment: Welcome!  Please could you clarify what you mean by "code writer"?  Is this an IDE or a code library?

Comment: `ProjectVersion.txt` simply holds the version you last opened the project with. If you know it you could insert it there yourself like e.g. `m_EditorVersion: 2019.3.3f1` (the fieldname however also depends on the version) I think laternatively you should be able to simply delete that file and open your project in Unity again. It has nothing to do with your code though ...

Comment: Hi I meant the script writer I am using to write c#

Comment: It show namespace error or (your files are corrupt )sometimes and I am clueless what it means as I have just started with unity in my middle school 8 grade and since it is a lockdown I cannot consult any teacher at any point of time except school hours.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you had custom layers, tag, or collision matrix set up, its perfectly safe to delete ProjectSettings.txt - it will be recreated on next unity start (after displaying a warning that the project was saved with an ancient verion of the editor, which will be safe to ignore)